# How to attach form-data file to postman test and run it via newman on different development environments?

Tags: gradle, postman

I have some postman test cases which test a file upload API. I use newman to run the collections as we have set a test stage in our CI/CD pipeline to run all collections using newman. For the moment this is how I set the files manually in the `collection.json`. This works fine for my local environment, but as soon as this hits the pipeline it fails. That is because newman gets executed by the gradle file and the file paths should be relative to the gradle file.

**Collection.json**

```
"body": {
    "mode": "formdata",
        "formdata": [
            {
                "key": "document",
                "type": "file",
                "src": "../../test_resources/test_documents/invalid/150kb.unsupftype"
            }
        ]
}
```

**gradle.build**

```
task postmanInMemory(dependsOn: ':core-app:startBackground', type: NodeTask) {
    logger.info("background task started. Running tests");
    script = file('scripts/newman.js')
    args = ['local']
}
```

I need a way to make sure that these file paths are always relative to the `collection.json`, not the `gradle.build` file.

Comment: Have you tried adding the file directory to the `-working-dir <path>` flag?
This sets the path of the working directory to use while reading files with relative paths. It default to the current directory.

Comment: @DannyDainton I will try this and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Just edit the collection and replace the hardcoded path with varaible by using {{pathvaraible}}

And pass the full file path as an environment variable.

eg value : C:\Users\guest\Desktop\1.JPG , don't need escape characters

Comment: But then again I have to hardcode the {{file_path}} value somewhere. I need this to be able to run on any OS environment.  In my case my development environment is on windows but the pipelines run on linux. That is why I used a relative path. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: @k9yosh you can pass value --env-var "filrpayh,=location" as command line switch in cicd

Comment: i have tried this and it gives me error no such file found have u tried it and works for you ?